# Looping over a string adds white space between characters in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a string inside an object, that I wanna loop over, to find specific characters(#), if it exists inside a database type text. So I go letter by letter, to check if it exists. But when I do that, it displays additional white space in between characters. The same setup worked fine in php. This line is inside an erb file. It is displayed inside a div. If I just do

```
<%= feed.text %>
```

It displays ok, but then I cant check if it has # inside.

---

Expected output: 
Hey

What I get: 
H e y

How would I fix this?

This is my code:

```
<div class='tweet-text'>                
   <% i = 0 %> 
   <%  while i < feed.text.length  do %>
        <%= feed.text[i] %>
        <% i += 1 %>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

Currently I just wanna get it displayed correctly, without the white space. And if it found #. And because there were questions, I wanna then color the #, to some color.

Comment: You have only shown us a snippet from - presumably - an `erb` file. How is that "output" actually being generated? There's nothing in the code you've provided to indicate how anything gets displayed.

Comment: Each `<%= feed.text[i] %>` outputs just one single character per line. That means between the characters there is actually whitespace – a line breaks and the whitespaces used to indent `<%= feed.text[i] %>`. Would you mind explaining what you actually want to achieve? And why you want to find specific characters?

Comment: Because then I want to color them to some color. How would I remove the indent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I then searched a more Ruby on Rails like solution, than above, so this then works for me to show any #word as a link, and it is much more simple.

```
<div class='tweet-text'>                
    <%= highlight(feed.text, /#\w+/, highlighter: '<a href="search?q=\1">\1</a>') %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple spaces between each letter, which is why the spaces are rendered this way.

Your code is not very ruby like, but if you are really keen to keep it the way it is, you could write it like this:

```
<div class='tweet-text'>                
  <% i = 0 %> 
  <% while i < text.length  do %><%= text[i] %><% i += 1 %><% end %>
</div>
```

Hopefully you'll revisit it and improve it.